# Get value from text file

Tags: c#, stream

I'm trying to get some text from a txt file if it exists.

The text file looks like this:

```
"account name","Server name"
"user1","serverX"
"user2","serverY"
"user3","serverZ"
```

Now what I want is when clicking on a button, it gets a value from input box and find in the text file, if it exists, it shows me "server data" next to it. Otherwise it shows "notfound"

For example: I type "user2" as input, click the button and it gives back: "serverY"

Here is where I'm at:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\test\\TestFile.txt"))
{
    String line = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
    if (lines.Contains("inputbox") {
        // How I'm telling him to get the server value
    } else {
        console.writeline("notfound");
    }
```

Now the if statement works as I tried it and it finds the inputbox in text but don't know how to tell him to get the data next to it.

Comment: Use `string.Split` to split the line and then take the last part...

Comment: The file is in comma-separated format, there are plenty of libraries / examples online for reading and parsing that into a usable data structure

Comment: But there a multiple lines that separated with comma. how am I telling him to take only the part belongs to that inputbox ?

Comment: You'd have to read through the lines until you come to the one you need. If you import the file into a structure like a DataTable you can more easily read each value within the row separately. Are you sure it wouldn't be easier if this data was in a database instead? Then you could directly query the row and column you want

Comment: Would be much easier but unfortunately I'm getting this file from third party application that I don't have over control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
    public static string GetServerNameForUser(string value)
    {
        // this part will wrap input with " e.g. "value"
        value = "\"" + value + "\"";
        string[] data = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\test\\TestFile.txt");
        foreach(string log in data)
        {
            string[] temp = log.Split(',');
            if(temp[0].Equals(value))
            {
                return temp[1];
            }
        }
        return "Not Found";
    }
```

Approach 2.

```
    public static string GetServerNameForUser(string value)
    {
        string[] data = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\test\\TestFile.txt");
        foreach(string log in data)
        {
            string[] temp = log.Split(',');
            if(temp[0].Contains(value))
            {
                return temp[1];
            }
        }
        return "Not Found";
    }
```

**Approach 3. Async Way**

```
    public static async Task<string> GetServerNameForUser(string value)
    {
        string[] data = await ReadAllLinesAsync("C:\\test\\TestFile.txt");
        foreach(string log in data)
        {
            string[] temp = log.Split(',');
            if(temp[0].Contains(value))
            {
                return temp[1];
            }
        }
        return "Not Found";
    }

    public static Task<string[]> ReadAllLinesAsync(string path)
    {
        return ReadAllLinesAsync(path, Encoding.UTF8);
    }

    public static async Task<string[]> ReadAllLinesAsync(string path, Encoding encoding)
    {
        var lines = new List<string>();

        // Open the FileStream with the same FileMode, FileAccess
        // and FileShare as a call to File.OpenText would've done.
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, DefaultBufferSize, DefaultOptions))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
                lines.Add(line);
            }
        }

        return lines.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Your split will return you two strings with `"`, so the Equals method is wrong here unless your value is not covered in `"`

Comment: The command used by async function that used by multiple users at the same time. (trying to avoid read blockage of the file and resource overkill) not sure if this would fit to my need.

Comment: @DanielA if your file is not being updated frequently only read it once and refer it every time in method will do the trick.

Comment: @MihirDave There is a way not to wrap the value ?  As you see the syntax of the list is "user","serv".   would be good find easy quick async way to do it. any other ideas ?

Comment: @DanielA Please look at Approach 3 for async solution

Comment: @MihirDave at the end I choose 'Approach 2' but had to finetune it as instead of "split + search" every line I let him search the content first and then split it : 
`foreach(string log in data)
        {
            
            if(log.Contains(value))
            {
                string[] temp = log.Split(',');
                return temp[1];
            }`

and had to use `.replace` to get rid of the /"   as the result was normally 
`"/"server123/""`  
by adding:
 `string[] temp = log.Split(',');
var s = temp[1].Replace("\"" , "");
return = s;`
thanks for you advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use linq, in that case you can write something like that

```
    public static string SearchData(IEnumerable<string> lst, string searchString)
    {
        var result = lst.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Split(',')[0].Contains(searchString));
        return result == null ? "not found" : result.Split(',')[1];
    }
```

and then call method

```
   var searchString = Console.ReadLine();
   var result = SearchData(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("data.txt"), searchString);
   Console.WriteLine(result);
   Console.ReadKey();
```

here is result:

[image]

If you want to search by whole word, not by a part, just replace `Contains` to `Equals`